# WebApi, iOS, and Forms Auth - can it work?

Tags: c#, ios, asp.net, cookies, asp.net-web-api

I have a single-page web application that makes AJAX calls to a WebAPI layer to provide all data. The web app authenticates and authorizes endpoints with the following:

```
WebSecurity.Login(model.Username, model.Password)
```

This way, I can use MembershipProvider to determine who can access what on a per-controller level:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/adminwork")]
[System.Web.Http.Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public HttpResponseMessage DoWork() {
    ApiResponseDto result = _adminService.DoAdminWork();
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
}
```

I'm preparing to build an iOS application that will use this same API.  I'm hoping that I can use this mechanism of forms auth + membership provider to attach a cookie to all requests originating from the mobile app, effectively treating requests in the same manner as those coming from the web app (and minimizing my work).

Is there any way to make an iOS application work with ASPX cookies to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use WebView to handle stuff with cookies, but I would call it very inappropriate way to authenticate api users. Insecure way.

> In particular, the MVC portion of your app might use forms authentication, which stores credentials in a cookie. Cookie-based authentication requires the use of anti-forgery tokens, to prevent CSRF attacks. That’s a problem for web APIs, because there is no convenient way for the web API to send the anti-forgery token to the client. (For more background on this issue, see Preventing CSRF Attacks in Web API.) Calling SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication ensures that Web API is not vulnerable to CSRF attacks from credentials stored in cookies.

You should use token based methods instead.
[Consider adding OAuth methods to your middleware](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api)

Comment: Yikes.  It looks like that would have a lot of implications on my application architecture.

Comment: How about implementing header validation to prevent those attacks?  http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-attacks

Comment: if I understood it right, this is for AJAX requests from MVC, server rendered page, not SPA or mobile apps

Comment: This is for a SPA with one MVC rendered page, and all other requests via AJAX

Comment: exactly. Why would you render it on mobile device? I always user token auth in WebAPI, works great for SPA and any other clients.

Comment: Because I *have already implemented* forms auth and want to minimize rework as long as I'm not posing a security risk by doing so.